# How to send and return a JSON response through a lambda function aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an a closure by Amazon webservices called lambda function with delegation defined as following:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Ev° %s', event)

    if event['action'] == "getPosition":
        getPosition(event, context)

def getPosition(event, context):

    # read position from file
    positionLoaded = readPosition(pId=int(json.loads(str(event['body']['id']))))

    # build response
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(positionLoaded, indent=4),
        "message": "OK",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    }

return response


# Reads position in json file from s3 Bucket with pId
def readPosition(pId: int):
    positionFromBucketJSON = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="bucketName", Key=str(pId) + ".json")
    return json.loads(positionFromBucketJSON['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

When I send a **request to the lambda function** as following:

```
{
  "action": "getPosition",
  "body": {
    "id": 2021152530123456
  }
}
```

I get an error **response from the lambda function** as following:

```
{"errorMessage": "'Not Found'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/positionService.py\", line 58, in lambda_handler\n    getPosition(event, context, callback=None)\n", "  File \"/var/task/positionService.py\", line 76, in getPosition\n    message = "not existing at all!"}
```

I don't know why since JSON-File **2021152530123456.json** do exist directly in s3 bucket.

Could you help to figure out what the error could be in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python Lambda function handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) takes 2 parameters (event, context), not 3 parameters (event, context, callback). You may have been reading JavaScript documentation, where a Lambda function handler has a 3rd parameter (callback).

Here is an example of a Python Lambda function that returns a JSON payload:

```
import json
        
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "id": 12,
            "description": "hoverboard"
        })
    }
```

In your original code, you have two additional problems:

1. your Lambda handler doesn't return anything (it should return `getPosition(event, context)`)
2. your getPosition() function's return statement is mis-indented (correct the indentation)

Comment: i,m going to check it out, and come back, thanks for the details, i have read that documentation also from many other ones. See you later then

Comment: i,m getting now **null** as return after update!

Comment: What does your current code look like? It's going to be difficult to diagnose something we can't see.

Comment: i just updated the question with newer code :)

Comment: the response looks like following: `{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
null
`

Comment: still here ? Could you find anything, i,m stuck on it right now :)

Comment: Your Lambda handler, as written, doesn't return anything. And your `getPosition()` function's return statement is mis-indented.

Answer (score -1):

I solve my issue by adding a **return** to the main lambda function while delegating to the getPosition(...) function, it look then like following:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Ev° %s', event)

    if event['action'] == "getPosition":
        return getPosition(event, context)
```